# Why does my AuthenticationManager get initialized twice in my tests when I start using method security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, auth0

I have a working Spring MVC app with the following security config:

```
package co.masslab.shiba;
// imports snipped

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint auth0EntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private Auth0AuthenticationFilter auth0Filter;

    @Autowired
    private Auth0AuthenticationProvider auth0AuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(auth0EntryPoint)
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(auth0Filter, SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(auth0AuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

When I add the annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` to the WebSecurityConfig class, and a `@PreAuthorize` annotation to a method in a controller class, the code still compiles cleanly, runs fine and behaves as expected. However, my tests start throwing an `AlreadyBuiltException` for the `AuthenticationManager`. The stack trace I get back is—to paraphrase Fermat—too large for this text box, but the outermost thread gives the following as its cause (linebreaks added):

```
Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'channelMarksController' defined in file [/Users/jason/Code/shiba/build/classes/main/co/masslab/shiba/transfer/ChannelMarksController.class]:
Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]:
Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field:
private com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationFilter co.masslab.shiba.WebSecurityConfig.auth0Filter;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'auth0Filter':
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field:
private org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.auth0.spring.security.auth0.Auth0AuthenticationFilter.authenticationManager;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/AuthenticationManagerConfiguration.class]:
Bean instantiation via factory method failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]:
Factory method 'authenticationManager' threw exception;

nested exception is org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AlreadyBuiltException:
This object has already been built
```

Since initialization only fails when testing, I would assume that the problem lies in my test class, but the above error is generated by the following vacuous test class:

```
package co.masslab.shiba;
// imports snipped

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=ShibaApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ShibaApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

What about the combination of method security and this test causes Spring to attempt to build the `AuthenticationManager` a second time?

Comment: This the above test class annotated differently than other test classes in any way?

Comment: @holmis83: The test classes are all annotated the same way, and they’re all throwing the same error.